# Using Proxy with CookieContainer

Tags: c#, proxy, webclient

I'm currently extending WebClient Class and want to access the server using Proxy
But my code throws Exception "Unable to connect to the remote server".
I've used this code before without Proxy and it is working fine.
Here is my Code Snippet.

```
 public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
    {
        private readonly CookieContainer m_container = new CookieContainer();
        //public override IWebProxy Proxy { get; set; }
        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {

            WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("93.79.133.235:3128");
            proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
            proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

            request.Proxy = proxy;

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
            if (webRequest != null)
            {
                webRequest.CookieContainer = m_container;
            }
            return request;
        }
}
```

am I missing something??
Please Help!!!!

and

```
CookieAwareWebClient client = new CookieAwareWebClient();
client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com/");
```

getting exception in this line and there are bunch of more request where this can happen n code but this is first occurrence of using the object of defined class.

Comment: @ Marc Gravell Please help me for this issue